# Discord.js error, while selecting a random object from a another javascript

Tags: discord.js

This is my code:

```js
// index.js:

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client ();
const names = require('./names');

bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '!randomname'){
        const embed0 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#ba0f0f')
            .setDescription("This is your random name: " + names.namelist[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.namelist.length)])
        message.channel.send(embed0);
    }
});
```

```js
// names.js:

const namelist = [
'Oscar',
'John',
'Emma',
]
```

This is the error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined **(**...names.namelist[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.namelist.**length**)])**)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your array:

```js
// array.js
const array = [
  1,
  2,
  3
];

module.exports = array;
```

```js
// main.js
const array = require('./array');

console.log(array.length);
```